# How can we create a drawer navigation in another component and just call it in the app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and working on react navigation 5. In react navigation 4, with the help of createAppContainer we can import our navigation component and call it in the app.js. how can we do the same thing with react navigation 5.

here's my code

```
//drawer Component
import AccountsScreen from "../screens/AccountsScreen";
import CategoriesScreen from "../screens/CategoriesScreen";
import FavouritesScreen from "../screens/FavouritesScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen";
import TrendsScreen from "../screens/TrendsScreen";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const AppDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#555",
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            drawerIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                style={{ fontSize: size, color: color }}
                name={focused ? "home" : "home-outline"}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Accounts" component={AccountsScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Trends" component={TrendsScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Favourites" component={FavouritesScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default AppDrawer;


//App.js
import React from "react";

import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import AppDrawer from "./route/AppDrawer";
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return <AppDrawer />;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

App.js

```
// ./App.js
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import DrawerNavigator from "./navigation/DrawerNavigator";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

DrawerNavigator.js

```
// ./navigation/DrawerNavigator.js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Contact from "../screens/Contact";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const screenOptionStyle = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#9AC4F8",
  },
  headerTintColor: "white",
  headerBackTitle: "Back",
};

const ContactStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};        

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={ContactStackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Comment: Not working Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string(for a built in components or a class/function(for composite components)but got: undefined. you likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: check "Contact" screen is there or not in your component